# Multiple Asynchronous HTTP Requests in Background iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, cocoa, http

I have an application that has many views (Using tab bar controller). I want to make concurrent asynchronous http requests, independently of the current view that the user is viewing. When an http request is responded , I want to update the User Interface, and then request again. If I write the code  inside a UIViewController Subclass, everything works fine. Where can I write my code so as to work , without knowing which tab the user is viewing? I would like to avoid using threads. Is that possible?

I have made a webservice that takes http requests and responds when it has something new. So, then i request for the new information and then i reopen the window for the webservice to talk me. That way I make a "persistent" connection.

Finally i would like to know, what is the best way to inform my model for the changes that will be made to it. NSNotification? Delegation?

**UPDATE**

The code below DOES NOT receive any response. It receives BAD_ACCESS and it crashes.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Request Data
    ConnectionHandler *connectionHandler = [[ConnectionHandler alloc] init];
    [connectionHandler requestSO];
    [connectionHandler requestSopen];
    // Make Root View Controller
    MainViewController *mainViewcontroller = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.window setRootViewController:mainViewcontroller];
    //
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is wrong to avoid threads but if you want to run all the processes from a central place maybe the appDelegate is one place you could do it from. Personally I would be doing all of the network requests inside the model.

Comment: Running your requests in a separate background thread (off the main thread) keeps your app user-interface responsive. If your ui is very unresponsive due to running all the processes on the main thread then your app might be killed by the os, and at very least your users will rate/review it very poorly. See http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial

Answer (score 2):

NSURLConnection is by default async unless you manually call sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error: , make a NSURLConnectionDelegate class  , set that class as the delegate of your model and use it to update your UI.

Comment: Where should i fire the http request? I need this code to be executed all the time. I do not now which screen the user will be viewing

Comment: Use a background thread... That way you can keep sending requests irrespective of what is getting executed on the main thread..

Comment: I would like to avoid threads. Is there any safer way to do it?

Comment: this class that is a NSURLConnectionDelegate would be allocated once and you would send requests to it at any time which while run concurrently , set this class as the delegate of your model or use notifications if you have multiple model points.

Comment: anything non synchronous like NSURLConnection uses threads but they are nothing you have to do with or worry about.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly do you mean. Can i have a simple example?

Comment: there is no simple example, but you can see Apple's example XMLPerformance  at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/XMLPerformance/Introduction/Intro.html